# Advice needed for choosing drop-down attic ladders

Tags: attic, storage, attic-conversion, attic-door

We are going to install a drop-down attic ladder for easier access to storage. I don't know anyone with one of these however and none of the local home improvement stores have any on display, they are all special order items so I can't go in and check some out in person. I'm trying to decide on if we should get an [aluminum ladder](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Louisville-Ladder-7-ft-8-in-to-10-ft-3-in-25-5-in-x-54-in-Aluminum-Attic-Ladder-with-375-lbs-Maximum-Load-Capacity-AA2510I/311317153), a [wooden ladder](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Werner-8-ft-10-ft-22-5-in-x-54-in-Wood-Attic-Ladder-with-250-lb-Maximum-Load-Capacity-WU2210/203017053), or one of the more expensive [scissor-style metal ladders](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Fakro-LST-9-ft-2-in-22-5-in-x-31-in-Insulated-Steel-Scissor-Attic-Ladder-with-350-lb-Load-Capacity-Not-Rated-66875/100672568). I want this to be a functional and easy to access space, so I don't mind paying more for a better ladder that will be easy to use. I'm looking for any advice from folks who have tried these different types of ladders and who can make any recommendations. I'm located in Canada as well in case that matters. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

All three serve pretty much the same function equally well. The wood ladder one is good for 250+- whereas the other two are good for 350+- range so that decision depends on your weight. I installed the wood ladder one in my house and it's worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

As @JACK says, any one of them will work. I have the aluminum folding type. It's very sturdy and I'm completely satisfied with it *as a ladder* to get **me** up and down from the attic over my workshop. But -- truth be told -- it's pretty awful for bring stuff up and down from the attic, especially heavy or bulky stuff. It's a ladder, it's not stairs.

Just think about it: if you wanted to take a big box of Christmas ornaments onto your roof with an extension ladder, how would you do it? You need to hold the box with both hands, which leaves no hands to hold onto the ladder. It's the same thing with an attic ladder.

That's why I built a dumb waiter powered by a winch to move heavy or bulky stuff into or out of the attic. The human uses the ladder, the stuff uses the dumb waiter.

(With apologies to any not-so-dumb waiters out there.)

Comment: I've rigged a block and tackle, for similar reasons but cheaper and easier. But I only use it for heavy things, and find it easier to push light boxes (like the Christmas stuff) up the aluminium drop down ladder as I climb.

Comment: Well, unless your attic is rated for loading, you probably shouldn't be hauling *really* heavy stuff up and down.

Comment: @Huesmann Ah, but it is! I had the trusses designed for load bearing, plans stamped and signed by an engineer. I currently have two tons of wood heating pellets distributed over a 24x30' section, less than half the allowed dead load, and at least a ton of steel and wood distributed over a 24x24' section. A third 24x24' section gets off easy with maybe half a ton of misc "stuff". The dumb waiter moves 400 lbs of pellets, 10 bags at a time. Got it covered!

Answer (score 0):

Objectively speaking, the aluminum one weighs less and supports more weight.

The scissor model is for extravagance.

I assume installation instructions will be similar regardless of your choice.

I replaced my wooden one with aluminum and have thoroughly enjoyed that decision every single time I use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a wooden one, be sure to get one that's got a good assistance spring system. They're heavy otherwise. Aluminium is light enough not to need a spring.

The instructions will probably say to put it in the centre of the gap, and it may come with a hand rail (non-structural) and dire warnings about what will happen if you don't use it. *I ignored both*, and placed it as far right in the space as I could. That means I've got more room to carry something like a suitcase in my left hand, holding the ladder with my right. I've also got more room to post tall things up there.

When fitting and testing it have another adult around, unless you're happy to get up and down with a stepladder and brute force. I had to lower myself down with nothing after pushing the stepladder to one side, a bit too hard.